# Unable to install 'secrets' on python 3.5 (pip, ubuntu 3.5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, python-3.5

I am trying to use the library **secrets** on Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04. It does not come with the python installation and I am not able to install it through pip. Is there a way to get it to work on python 3.5?

Comment: What errors do you see when trying to install it with pip?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fact that there is no PyPi module for this and Ubuntu uses ancient python versions is pretty annoying, it would be nice if someone could fix this. In the meantime:

To generate secrets in older versions of Python (>= 2.4 and <= 3.5) you can use the [`urandom` function from the os library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom).

Example:

```
from os import urandom

urandom(16) # same as token_bytes(16)
urandom(16).hex() # same as token_hex(16) (python >=3.5)
```

To make something backwards compatible that still uses the new secrets library when supported you could do something like

```
try:
    from secrets import token_hex
except ImportError:
    from os import urandom
    def token_hex(nbytes=None):
        return urandom(nbytes).hex()
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `urandom()` does not have the same "reasonable default" rule when the number of bytes requested is `None`. So your backwards compatible solution would need to manually set `nbytes` to some "reasonable default" (though I'm not sure how many people use this feature).

Answer (score 10):

You can use the backport of the secrets module for Python 2.7, 3.4 and 3.5 by the name of **[python2-secrets](https://pypi.org/project/python2-secrets/)**. (the name is a bit confusing in my opinion)

Installation:

```
pip install --user python2-secrets
```

Comment: lovely for a short solution.

Answer (score 2):

The module you are trying to use wasn't part of Python as of version 3.5.

It looks like in that version secrets can't be downloaded from pip either

```
$ pip install secrets
Collecting secrets
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement secrets (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for secrets
```

When working under a Python 3.6 environment that module can be imported right away, as it's part of the standard library:

```
Python 3.6.3 (default, Mar  7 2018, 21:08:21)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import secrets
>>> print(secrets)
<module 'secrets' from '/home/mikel/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/secrets.py'>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x use `pip install secret` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [PEP 506](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0506/#id51), the proposal talks about how `secrets` is implemented and points to a [Bitbucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/sdaprano/secrets/src/default/) by the author of the package itself, which is now part of the official Python Standard Library!